# Possible shortcut to integrate the double integral $\iint \frac{1}{x^2+y^2-2x+6y+20} dA$ over a region

Tags: integration, substitution

This problem was on math homework. Integrate the following double integral over the region D = {($x, y$) | $x^2+y^2 \le 2x-6y+15$}
$$\iint \frac{1}{x^2+y^2-2x+6y+20}dA$$
This problem was supposed to be solved with a change of variables to polar coordinates, but I realized that the domain and the integral looked very similar. So, I used the substitution $u = x^2+y^2-2x+6y+20$, which has a minimum value of $10$. The domain becomes $u \le 35$. Thus, the bounds for $u$ are $10$ to $35$. My integral becomes $$\int_{10}^{35} \frac{1}{u} du.$$
Which evaluates to $ln(7/2)$. The actual answer is $\pi ln(7/2)$. The discrepancy comes from the fact that I did not convert $dA$ to $du$ properly. I tried using a Jacobian, but that only works if I used a two variable substitution. So, I'm not sure what I have to do to get my shortcut to work, assuming it's even possible to get it to.

Comment: The statement of the integral in the title is different from what is in the body.  Anyway, try translated polar coordinates... something like $x-1 = r\cos \theta, y+3 = r\sin\theta$

Comment: Hint: $$x^2+y^2-2x+6y+20 = (x-1)^2+(y+3)^2+?$$ and $$x^2+y^2\leq2x-6y+15\implies (x-1)^2+(y+3)^2\leq ?$$

Comment: @DougM I know that polar coordinates works, I'm trying to find an easier way to solve the problem using my substitution

Comment: @DougM I made a mistake in the body, I corrected the integral. It should be $x^2 +y^2$ not just $x^2$

Comment: @AnneBauval Oh I misread your comment. The correct answer is $\pi ln(7/2)$ not $\pi ln(3/2)$

Comment: @AnneBauval The last integral evaluates to $ln(35) - ln(10)$ which equals $ln(35/10)$ or $ln(7/2)$ instead of $ln(3/2)$

Comment: You could probably make your method work (though it's not clear whether it would remain a "short"cut) by inserting a factor that is the length of the curve (here a circle) for which $u$ takes a particular value. This is somewhat like the "washer method" when calculating volumes of solids of revolution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an artificial way to proceed, so that the missing $\pi$-factor from the posted question falls transparently. To find the right scene for the tricky substitution, i need a more symmetric setting, so let me use first the linear, cheap substitution:
$$
\begin{aligned}
x-1 &=5X\ ,\\
y+3 &=5Y\ .\\[2mm]
\end{aligned}
$$
We will then use:
$$
\bbox[yellow]{\qquad u =x^2 +y^2 -2x+6y+20=25(X^2+Y^2)+10\ .\qquad }
$$
The domain of integration is $(x-1)^2+(y+3)^6\le 5^2$, i.e. $X^2+Y^2\le 1$.
I will not pass to polar coordinates. Instead, consider a new variable,
$s$,
to complete $u$ to a adequate pair for the change of variables, thus to pass from $(x,y)$ to $(X,Y)$, and finally to $(s,u)$:
$$
\bbox[yellow]{\qquad s=\arctan\frac XY\qquad\ .\ }
$$
It takes values between
$\arctan(-\infty)=-\frac \pi2$
and
$\arctan(\infty)=\frac \pi2$.
To have a bijection at the last step, we may restrict in between to $Y>0$.
This is ok, since we integrate an even function w.r.t. $Y$.
Then we have formally:
$$
\begin{aligned}
dx&=5\; dX\ , &du &=2\cdot 25\cdot(X\;dX+Y\;dY)& \\
dy&=5\; dY\ , &ds &=\frac 1{X^2+Y^2}\cdot(Y\; dX-X\;dY) \\[3mm]
dx\wedge dy&=25\; dX\wedge dY\ , & ds\wedge du &=
\frac {2\cdot 25}{X^2+Y^2}\cdot(Y^2\; dX\wedge dY-X^2\;dY\wedge dX)\\
&&&= 2\cdot 25\cdot dX\wedge dY\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
and we can now calculate the wanted integral, denote it by $J$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
J &=\iint_D\frac {dx\; dy}{x^2 +y^2-2x+6y+20}
\\
&=\iint_{X^2+Y^2\le 1}\frac {25\; dX\; dY}{25(X^2 +Y^2)+10}
\\
&=2\iint_{\substack{X^2+Y^2\le 1\\ Y>0}}\frac {25\; dX\; dY}{25(X^2 +Y^2)+10}
\\
&=2\iint_{\substack{u\in[25\cdot 0+10,\ 25\cdot 1+10]\\s\in[-\pi/2,\ +\pi/2]}}
\frac {\frac 12\; ds\; du}u
=\int_{0+10}^{25+10}\frac {du}u=\log 35-\log 10
\\
&=\bbox[yellow]{\color{maroon}{\boxed{\quad \log\frac{35}{10}\quad}}}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
$\square$

---

Yes, using this trick, we integrate in between a clean $du/u$. (And well, i'm afraid somebody will still say i was using polar coordinates... But else, there is no way to involve a clean $du/u$, respecting the wish from the question, making the "almost coincidence" work.)

Answer (score 0):

Your $u=x^2+y^2-2x+6y+20$ can be completed for instance by $v=y,$ so
$$I:=\iint_{x^2+y^2 \le 2x-6y+15}\frac1{x^2+y^2-2x+6y+20}dxdy$$$$=2\iint_{(v+3)^2+10\le u\le35}\frac1u\frac{dudv}{2\sqrt{u-10-(v+3)^2}}$$
(the $2$ in front of the RHS stands for the fact that $x-1$ is determined only up to sign by $(u,v)$).

Letting $s=\frac{v+3}{\sqrt{u-10}},$
$$\int_{(v+3)^2\le u-10}\frac{dv}{2\sqrt{u-10-(v+3)^2}}=\int_{-1}^1\frac{ds}{2\sqrt{1-s^2}}=\frac\pi2$$
hence
$$I=2\int_{10}^{35}\frac\pi2\frac{du}u=\pi\ln\frac72.
$$